# SourceTree creates commit unlinked with branches

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree connected with remote repository. Sometimes, when I commit, it generates a strange behavior. It creates a commit like "Merge tag '1.0.1' into develop" and the result is a line like this:

[image]

The yellow line is generated at the commit and goes all the way to the bottom. This is a simple example. But I had a project where it had 4+ of these cases, which is really weird and annoying.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I only use SourceTree occasionally, and my team doesn't make heavy use of tags. I've never seen this issue, but that doesn't mean a whole lot. Have you tried looking at their [bug/feature tracker](https://jira.atlassian.com/projects/SRCTREE/issues/)? Maybe you can find something in there.

Comment: (Or the [windows version...](https://jira.atlassian.com/projects/SRCTREEWIN/issues/))

Comment: @JDB Yes I did tried looking there. But I don't even know how to look for this type of issue. The weid thing is that I'm not even commiting it using tag or tag message.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, then you might want to report it in their tracker. You'll probably get better results than you will on SO. If you find an answer, you can always come back and add an answer to your question if you think it'll be helpful for other users.